# Часто используемые шаблоны проектирования в веб-приложении

Tags: веб-программирование, шаблоны-проектирования, web-apps

Какие шаблоны проектирования в веб-приложении наиболее часто используются? Подскажите, пожалуйста, из своего опыта, если можно, с примерами.

Пока что для себя в asp.net использовал dependency injection, и repository.

Comment: на ASP.NET MVC использовал `Lazy Initialization, Publisher/Subscriber, Singleton, etc...`

Comment: А если можно пример ситуации в которой возможно использование данных шаблонов?

Comment: - Lazy Initialization использовал для инициализации Compiled Query, делегатов AsyncFunc и некоторых других членов классов
- в качестве синглтонов у меня были статические классы, которые обеспечивали long polling 
- Publisher/Subscriber в качестве стандартных event`ов у меня освобождали из ожидания запросы всё того же long polling, которые тригеррили всё теже AsyncFunc

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что наиболее часто используемый шаблон - это шаблон фабрика. Примеров показать не могу, так-как не часто балуюсь таким, но в коде других разработчиков это встречается часто.